# Theme installed on local host isn't responding

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, localhost

I have uploaded the quick start package of the theme on my localhost Wamp server and it displayed the demo site perfectly, but whenever I click on any product or, try to dive in deep in demo website by clicking any category, it shows:

The requested **URL /sm-g3-quickstart/product.html** was not found on this server.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w48Wi.png]

**Please help me how to solve this** and if I upload this demo website on the live server then also this problem will show?
Thanks in advance

Comment: can u try to go on admin page and check whether the url rewrite option is enabled or disabled

Comment: @BKarthikKumar where will i get url rewrite option ?

Comment: first check in admin panel the category and products exist or not

Comment: @AdityaGupta, put the index.php at your url at URL /sm-g3-quickstart/index.php/product.html, then problem will solve

Comment: @AdityaGupta jus to go to system > configuration > General > Web
there you will get search engine optimization 
Use Web Server Rewrites set to no

Comment: @PiyushSuthar  yes all the categories and products exist

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara  It worked thank you

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara do i have to put it everytime i click on any product?  Is there a permanent fix to this problem. And if i upload this localhost website to live server will the problem remain same ?

Comment: @AdityaGupta set option to no in  system > configuration > General > Web > url rewrites index.php will appear

Comment: @AdityaGupta, no. go to system > configuration > General > Web > url rewrites put yes.

Comment: i have posted the answer. check once

Comment: @BKarthikKumar Thank You it worked. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all, check in admin panel
2. Go to System > Configuration > General > Web > Search Engine Optimization> Use Web Server Rewrites set to yes.
3. Check .htaccess file is in your root or not.
4. If not upload that file into root.
5. Clear cache.

Comment: Web>Url rewrite option is not there  instead there is search engine optimization> Use Web Server Rewrites  set to  yes . I have set this option from "yes" to "No" and it worked now.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: With setting it to "yes" it is not working

Comment: @AdityaGupta, Hi Good mng, upload .htaccess file to root, change configuration to default at admin panel > system > configuration > left top